# BPS process data fails to be deployed in DAS using KPISample

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-business-process

Using wso2bps-3.5.1, wso2das-3.0.1

Hi,

I've followed [the instructions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/Monitoring+a+BPEL+Process+with+WSO2+DAS) for deploying and testing the KPISample process that comes with BPS.

I'm able to include the extension bundle, deploy the project .zip file and execute a couple of process call without any errors.

But, I'm not getting any stream definitions deployed in the DAS. According to the [instructions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/Monitoring+a+BPEL+Process+with+WSO2+DAS) that is expected to happen automatically when sending data from BPS.

As I said, no errors in log files on either BAS or BPS.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create the stream and receiver first in DAS. Not mentioned in the tutorial.